# R coding string

Tags: string, r, parsing

I have a list of 96 files that I would like to open and perform some functions on the data.  I am VERY new to R, and am unsure how to manipulate strings to open the sequential file names.  Here is my code below, which clearly does not work:

```
for (N in (1:96)){
  if (N > 10) 
      TrackID <- "000$N"
  }
  else{
      TrackID <- "00$N"
  }

  fname_in <- 'input/intersections_track_calibrated_jma_from1951_$TrackID.csv'
  fname_out <- 'output/tracks_crossing_regional_polygon_$TrackID.csv'

  ......data manipulations.....

}
```

So basically I just need to be able to, for instance, when N=1, reference a file called intersections_track_calibrated_jma_from1951_0001.csv.

Thanks in advance!

Kimberly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `paste` and `paste0` to generate strings like this instead.

```
for (N in (1:96)){
  if (N > 10) 
      TrackID <- paste0("000",N)
  }
  else{
      TrackID <- paste0("00",N)
  }

  fname_in <- paste0('input/intersections_track_calibrated_jma_from1951_', 
                     TrackID.'.csv')
  fname_out <- paste0('output/tracks_crossing_regional_polygon_',
                      TrackID,'.csv')

  ......data manipulations.....

}
```

`paste0` just saves you from writing `sep=""` if you don't require a seperator (as in your case)

Comment: Hmmm I'm having trouble with the paste0 function.  Do I need a special library to use it?

Comment: @user1716877 No, but you do need an up-to-date R. Change `paste0(foo)` to `paste(foo, sep = "")` for similar results on an older R.

Comment: It's pasteZERO not pasteOH. What version of R are you using? I think this has been in for a year, at least...

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are looking for is the [**sprintf()**](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/sprintf.html) function...
`sprintf` will save you from having the tests on n, to known how many leading zeros are needed.
Combined with the [**paste()** or **paste0**](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/paste.html) function, producing the desired file name becomes a one-liner.
Indeed it would be possibly to just use the sprintf() function alone, as in
`sprintf("intersections_track_calibrated_jma_from1951_%04d.csv", n)` but having a function to produce the file names and/or the "TrakID" may allow to hide all these file naming convention details away.

Below, see sprintf() and paste0() in action, in the context of a convenience function created to produce the filename given a number n.

```
> GetFileName <- function(n) 
    paste0("intersections_track_calibrated_jma_from1951_",
           sprintf("%04d", n),
           ".csv")

> GetFileName(1)
[1] "intersections_track_calibrated_jma_from1951_0001.csv"
> GetFileName(13)
[1] "intersections_track_calibrated_jma_from1951_0013.csv"
> GetFileName(321)
[1] "intersections_track_calibrated_jma_from1951_0321.csv"
>
```

Of course, you could make the GetFileName function more versatile by adding parameters, some of which with a default value. In that fashion it could be used for both input and output file name (or any other file prefix/extension). For example:

```
GetFileName <- function(n, prefix=NA, ext="csv") {
   if (is.na(prefix)) {
      prefix <- "intersections_track_calibrated_jma_from1951_"
   }

   paste0(prefix, sprintf("%04d", n), ".", ext)
}
> GetFileName(12)
[1] "intersections_track_calibrated_jma_from1951_0012.csv"
> GetFileName(12, "output/tracks_crossing_regional_polygon_", "txt")
[1] "output/tracks_crossing_regional_polygon_0012.txt"
> GetFileName(12, "output/tracks_crossing_regional_polygon_")
[1] "output/tracks_crossing_regional_polygon_0012.csv"
>
```